# How do I enable Hibernation on a Sony VAIO VGN-NS235J?

Tags: 11.10, vaio, sony

I use Ubuntu 11.10 on my old SONY VAIO VGN-NS235J

I works very smooth and is fast in every aspect.

One problem i am facing is that I can't Hibernate it as I can do it on Windows earlier, how do i Enable it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to modify policykit to allow hibernation in upower?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-modify-policykit-to-allow-hibernation-in-upower)

Comment: Is your swap file greater in size than the amount of memory on your system?

Answer (score 1):

There is a question and a bug report associated with this:

[How to enable hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-modify-policykit-to-allow-hibernation-in-upower)

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-session/+bug/910183

The bug report mentions a workaround this.