# How to enable hibernation?

Tags: power-management, hibernate

In Ubuntu 12.04 and newer, [hibernation has been disabled by default in policykit](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-desktop-privileges/+bug/812394). How can I enable this back?

Comment: Why did they disable it in the first place? Does it have anything to do with losing audio?

Comment: for 13.10 see http://askubuntu.com/questions/361734/hibernation-is-still-missing-from-menu-in-13-10-after-enabling-via-polkit-how-t

Comment: To answer Ali's question, it was disabled because many people had problems hibernating due to problems with their swap partitions. However, in Ubuntu 14.10 Utopic Unicorn, there are plans to get hibernation working for good, with a button and everything.

Comment: For 15.04, you may need this question http://askubuntu.com/q/614662/178596

Comment: Hibernate might not work when `btrfs` partition is used. See here http://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: for 18.04, see https://askubuntu.com/a/1064114/921494

Answer (score 340, accepted):

**If this answer does not work in Ubuntu 13.10, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/362499/178596) for an alternative answer**

---

Hibernation was [disabled](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-desktop-privileges/+bug/812394) on 12.04 for machines that are not certified with Ubuntu.

In order to enable hibernation you need to test whether it works correctly by running `sudo pm-hibernate` in a terminal. The system will try to hibernate. If you are able to start the system again then you are more or less safe to add an override.

To do so, start editing:

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

Fill it with this:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Or in 14.04 and later:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default for login1]
  Identity=unix-user:*
  Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
  ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate for multiple users by default in logind]
  Identity=unix-user:*
  Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
  ResultActive=yes
```

Save by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>O</kbd> then <kbd>enter</kbd> and then exit nano by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd>.

Restart and hibernation is back!

Or run `killall unity-panel-service` to just reset the menu.

Some users will then need to run `sudo update-grub` to get the hibernate option to be available in the power menu.  Some users may also have to at least log out then log in to get it to appear in the (upper right) power menu.

Comment: This solution also works in GNOME shell 3.4 with the "Alternative Status Menu" extension.

Comment: unity --reset is now deprecated in Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I tried this in Ubuntu 12.10 but it didn't work (using gnome not unity). Any ideas?

Comment: I found a solution that worked super well here: http://www.krank.se/?p=373 in order for this to appear in the menu for Gnome 3.6

Comment: Fixed the Unity part.

Comment: How to undo this?

Comment: Didn't work for me on 12.10. Had to delete this file to start Ubuntu or it would get stuck with "Checking battery state...".

Comment: Weird. `sudo pm-hibernate` does absolutely nothing for me. It just prints a newline character and goes back to my bash prompt.

Comment: @cuda.geek yep, not gonna bother with the whole gui thing anymore, typing this little command is faster (even faster with alias...) :)

Comment: Really? Is this the user friendlier version of changing such a simple setting? It's getting uglier every day...

Comment: reboot is not necessary, log-out and log-in does the work. can safely say that for 13.04

Comment: Enabling a setting that will cause many people grief need not be user friendly. Particularly when it's as easy as following the instructions above.  People who can't use google or command line should not be able to do it.  Ideally the function could be fixed so it works more consistently before it reintroduced as default

Comment: I don't think that was Esteban's point. It shouldn't require arcane magic to enable hibernate. Think of something in the /etc/default directory where you change one line from enable_hibernate="false" to enable_hibernate="true". Think of having a system->settings dialog that just lets you turn it on with a warning "this may not work, your machine may not wake up properly."

Comment: what's the difference between this answer and modifying the already-existent entries in `/var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/10-vendor.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla` to "yes"?

Comment: For this to work on my Ubuntu 14.01 ttyl, I had to use Action value as org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate [Ref: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lxsession/+bug/1300798]

Comment: didn't work for mint 17

Comment: It doesn't work for me in ***Ubuntu 15.04***, I tried the menu reset, the laptop reset, but hibernation option in the menu doesn't appear.  But this one: http://askubuntu.com/a/487282/260677 does work for me,  so for those, who has an issue with the original solution, please, consider trying this one too.

Answer (score 53):

First you need to test your machine supports hibernation. Test it with the command:

```
 sudo pm-hibernate # if not found install with "apt install pm-utils"
 # or for newer Ubuntus above 17.04
 sudo systemctl hibernate
```

## Ubuntu 16.04 and above

For enabling in the interface you'll need to run `sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` and fill with:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=yes
```

## Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04

For enabling in the interface you'll need to run `sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/52-enable-hibernation.conf` for Ubuntu 14.04 and 15.04 and fill with:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default]
  Identity=unix-user:*
  Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
  ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default for login1]
  Identity=unix-user:*
  Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
  ResultActive=yes
```

It has several stanzas as you might have multiple users (so that is doesn´t depend of multiple-users or upower as manager instead of login1)

p.s.: official documentation https://help.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html

Comment: It worked for me on ***Ubuntu 15.04***, while the original accepted answer does not.

Comment: @MikeB. This worked because since Ubuntu 15.04, the core Ubuntu system starts using systemd- a newer replacement for the old upstart. The last section in the above code having "logind" is for systemd based systems. Hope this sheds some light to your situation. :D

Comment: Worked for me on  **ubuntu 16.04**. only issue was permission denied error which i solved using `sudo`.

Comment: The first step `sudo pm-hibernate` results in `command not found`.  I also tried `sudo apt install sudo pm-hibernate`, which also isn't available.  This is version Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: Your answer should appear at the top of the list, even though it has fewer votes it is more meaningful to visitors using today's software.

Comment: @L.D.James , `sudo apt install pm-utils laptop-mode-tools`

Comment: I am running 18.04. `sudo pm-hibernate` works on cmd line. `sudo systemctl hibernate` does not. The menu option seems to use the latter, not the former. How can I force it to use `pm-hibernate` ?

Answer (score 33):

Additionally, for those who want to disable the suspend button (for various reasons), proceed analogously...

Choose any file name, but this is one is verbose/convention:

```
sudoedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.disable-suspend.pkla
```

Fill it with this:

```
[Disable suspend by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.suspend
ResultActive=no
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

No need to restart, it should be gone as soon as you go into the shutdown menu.

Comment: You mean: `ResultActive=yes`

Comment: No, this should be `ResultActive=no`. The answer specifies that this to *disable* suspend.

Answer (score 14):

One more thing:

When you want to add the hibernation option to **XFCE**'s panel, you have to right-click your name (topright) and select `properties`.

After that a screen pops up:

[image]

Make sure, you check Hibernate like I did.

Answer (score 14):

First, I do recommend that you test if your laptop supports hibernation, because the reason why hibernation is disabled by default is because it sometimes has fatal results on some machines. Test your machine by

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and then `sudo pm-hibernate`

Your machine should hibernate. Wake your machine up after hibernation and observe if it misbehaves or if it acts normally. If you experience any abnormality after the hibernation, then I advise you don't continue with the following procedure. However, if it works just fine, continue to activate hibernation by

```
sudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

Edit the opened file and add this lines:

```
[Re-enable hibernation]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

After this, restart your machine, and upon login, you should see a hibernation option on the top right settings corner.

Comment: Why the rollback?

Comment: it was a mistaken rollback

Answer (score 6):

## Enabling hibernation with a script

I have translated above answers to `bash` scripts. This makes installation on multiple machines less tiresome.

Script `enable-hibernate`:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# https://askubuntu.com/a/94963/164341
cat << '_EOF_' |sudo tee /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
[Enable Hibernate]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
_EOF_
clear
echo
echo 'Hibernate enabled.'
echo
```

Script `disable-suspend`:

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# https://askubuntu.com/a/154821/164341
cat << '_EOF_' |sudo tee /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.disable-suspend.pkla
[Disable suspend by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.suspend
ResultActive=no
_EOF_
clear
echo
echo 'Suspend disabled.'
echo
```

Note: Do not forget to `chmod +x` both scripts to make them executable.

Answer (score 5):

If the response with `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` does not work as in my case, don't forget to delete the file by:

```
sudo rm /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

And try to use [TuxOnIce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TuxOnIce).

---

First ensure you have enough of swap. It should be the same size or bigger as the amount of your RAM. Use command

```
free
```

rule Swap > Mem. If this is not the case, enlarge your swap size. Then install TuxOnIce by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:tuxonice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install tuxonice-userui linux-generic-tuxonice linux-headers-generic-tuxonice
```

Then you can try to do a hibernate test run by:

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

Do not forget to save your work before you do it.

If all went fine, your computer will switch off. After switching it on, you will get your desktop in the state you left in it before hibernation.

Comment: tuxonice works also for me, while Ubuntu 14.04 native hibernation fails for some reason!

Comment: This no longer works as newer Ubuntu version cannot use this PPA.

Answer (score 4):

A simple command which does the exact same thing as the accepted answer except non-interactively:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
[Re-enable hibernate by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
EOF
```

Answer (score 3):

In 12.04, I successfully enabled hibernate option in the indicator menu to hibernate. But Still I wasn't able to successfully resume from hibernate. I did follow these steps to fix this problem:

### Enable Hibernate in 12.04

To enable Hibernate, I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/94963/61218) from Dima.

After enabling hibernate, I could hibernate. But the problem is, I can't successfully resume from hibernate. Any time I start my PC from hibernate, it boots like a normal boot. So, I had to do these things to be able to resume from hibernate.

### The fixes to be able to resume from hibernate

There is two way to fix this.

#### 1. Editing the `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file

1. First get the UUID of the swap partition.

   ```
    sudo blkid | grep swap
   ```

   This will output a line similar to this:

   ```
   /dev/sda12: UUID="a14f3380-810e-49a7-b42e-72169e66c432" TYPE="swap"
   ```

   The actually line will not match with this. Copy the value of UUID in between `"..."` double quote.
2. Open the resume file

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
   ```

   And in that file, add a line like this

   ```
   RESUME=UUID=a14f3380-810e-49a7-b42e-72169e66c432
   ```

   Don't forget to replace the actual UUID value you get from step 1. Save the file and exit gedit
3. Then in terminal, execute this command

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

You will now be able to resume from hibernation

#### 2. Editing the `/etc/default/grub` file.

1. Open a terminal and execute the below command to open it

   gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
2. There will be a line like  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
     . Edit the line to insert `RESUME=UUID=<your-uuid-value-here>` after the word `splash`.

   For example in my case, the line looks like this after editing

   ```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=a14f3380-810e-49a7-b42e-72169e66c432"
   ```

   Make sure, you used your UUID value you get from `sudo blkid | grep swap` command.
3. Then do this command

   ```
    sudo update-grub
   ```

This also enable you to successfully get resumed from hibernate.

---

<sup>Tested on two Ubuntu installation, both worked</sup>

Comment: file this as a seperate question & answer. As people may search for "fail to resume from suspend" and not find your excellent write up.

Comment: After your suggestion, I created this self-answered question http://askubuntu.com/questions/196364/i-have-enabled-hibernate-but-it-isnt-working-what-can-i-do

Comment: this worked for me (option #2) in Ubuntu 18.04 also, Thanks !!

Answer (score 1):

I have Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 amd64 on my notebook. I did the following to enable hibernation:

$ `sudo apt-get install hibernate` ([source](https://askubuntu.com/a/397151))

This installed also `libx86-1`[`uswsusp`](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate)`vbetool`

Then I could successfully hibernate with `sudo systemctl hibernate`. There is no `pm-hibernate` executable in my path.

$ `sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla`

Inserted: ([source](https://websetnet.com/enable-hibernate-option-ubuntu-16-10-system/))

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.handle-hibernate-key;org.freedesktop.login1;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-ignore-inhibit
ResultActive=yes
```

Installed https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/755/hibernate-status-button/