# How do you hibernate/suspend Ubuntu like Windows or both at the same time?

Tags: windows, dual-boot, suspend, hibernate, sleep

I'm using an ASUS laptop with Windows 7, and I just installed Ubuntu alongside Windows yesterday, using the no-risk option. I noticed, though, that I can't hibernate Ubuntu the way I did with Windows to save time, and, every time I use Ubuntu, I have to shut down to go into Windows, which has a slow boot.

Is there any way that I could have Windows and Ubuntu hibernated at the same time so I can access both easily (preferably without having to hit a function key within seconds). When I try to hibernate or suspend Ubuntu with Windows shut down, the screen just turns blue and doesn't shut the computer off like a Windows hibernate or sleep.

Comment: [This thread](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-modify-policykit-to-allow-hibernation-in-upower) may help you out

Comment: Check if your swap partition is crypted. Resume wont work if it is.

Answer (score 2):

Hibernating is not supported with the wubi installation.

http://wubi.sourceforge.net/faq.php

You'll have to migrate to a dedicated partition or reinstall properly to be able to hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using 12.04, Hibernate/suspend is apparently no longer supported or enabled by default, because it has been unreliable :(

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop#line-52