# How can I activate Hibernate on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable hibernation in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04)

I cannot select the option to Hibernate under Energy settings. Is there a way to put it back? (it worked on Ubuntu 11.10 :( )