# Hibernate was working on 11.10 and is not anymore on 12.04

Tags: hibernate, thinkpad

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable hibernation in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04)

I have a Thinkpad T400s which was using Ubuntu 11.10 until yesterday. I never shut down the system and was using hibernate constantly and without problems.
After upgrading to 12.04 I was surprised not to find hibernate in the power menu anymore.
A quick search showed me how to enable it again, but the bad news is that it does not work anymore. Meaning that it does not come back after the hibernation: I get to the screen with the ubuntu logo and the five white dots under it which turn red one after the other.
The screen then freezes before the last one turns red.

It cannot be a question of new hardware or problematic old hardware because hibernate was working before.
If anybody can help, this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Pls read it https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PrecisePangolin/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuDesktop. hibernation is disabled by default on 12.04.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

I searched your query and found [this](http://it-diary.com/linux/ubuntu-linux/enable-hibernation-in-ubuntu-12-04/). Hope this works

Comment: Thanks, but as I wrote I did see how to enable it again, which I did. My problem is that it does not come back after hibernation. And the reason is not "new hardware" as written in the official motivation behind disabling hibernate by default.