# Fix hibernate on Thinkpad X60 with 12.04 Precise Pangolin

Tags: 12.04, hibernate, thinkpad

I own a ThinkPad X60, hibernate used to work on 10.04 Lucid Lynx, but no longer works correctly on 12.04.

I am aware of [how to enable hibernate in Power Manager](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04).

The problem here is, in the default configuration, `pm-hibernate` works, but the system fails to resume correctly. There is no video glitch, black screen or other. The resume process just freezes on the Ubuntu splash boot after a few seconds of disk activity.

Is there a way to fix the system configuration so hibernates works again?

Answer (score 1):

Since the solution I found for this is not trivial, I wanted to post it here for the record.

I read the man page for `pm-hibernate`, and in the section on the `HIBERNATE_MODE` configuration option, I saw a mention of the `/sys/power/disk` file. I remembered that a few years ago I used to debug suspend and hibernate by writing to `/sys/power/state`. The possible values can be seen by reading the file.

I tested kernel-level hibernation with `sudo sh -c 'echo disk > /sys/power/state'`. The system suspended and resumed correctly.

So the problem was that `pm-hibernate` was doing something wrong.

I tried setting the `SLEEP_MODULE` option by creating a file `/etc/pm/config.d/sleep_module` with the content:

```
SLEEP_MODULE=tuxonice
```

And that fixed resuming after `pm-hibernate`.

Then, I needed to create a file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla` as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04).

And I had a fully working hibernate feature for my ThinkPad X60.

There is probably a bug to be filed in Launchpad about this, but I do not know what it would be.

I have had some stability issues with hibernate since applying this fix. So far, it has failed to resume once, and it failed to hibernate once. So be careful. Another sleep module might be more reliable, but I cannot test that until I can reproduce the problems.

Comment: I do have some stability issues with hibernate after this fix. So far, it failed to resume once, and it failed to hibernate once. So be careful. Another sleep module might be more reliable, but I cannot test that until I can reproduce the problems.

Answer (score 1):

Dell Latitude E6500 here. I had the same problem. Here's what fixed it:

`sudo apt-get purge uswsusp`

`SLEEP_MODE` is in default kernel mode. Now it hibernates like a champ. Apparently, uswsusp works imprecisely with the Precise Pangolin.

Answer (score 1):

Following ddaa's advice, I set SLEEP_MODULE=tuxonice on my Lenovo T420s. That improved matters: sometimes my computer comes back from hibernation properly, sometimes the screen remains half grey, half black. It's only the display that fails since I can still log on blindly with ctrl+alt f1, then do a pm-suspend, and after the computer wakes up the display is back.

As a workaround, do a 'sudo pm-hibernate' to hibernate without locking the screen. When the display doesn't wake up, simply press the suspend button Fn-F4 (the half moon) and switch the computer back on. This resets the screen.

Comment: No fix, but a workaround. Been able to hibernate for a week now :)

Comment: I simply type sudo pm-hibernate to prevent locking the suspend key. If the display fails on wake-up I press Fn-F4 (suspend) and switch the computer back on. Until now, always worked.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification (and +1 for the workaround).  Can you edit your answer to include the info in your comments in the actual answer (since comments here have second-class status, and are always in danger of disappearing)? Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Similar problem here, using HP FOLIO 13 and Ubuntu 12.04. pm-hibernate power off but when I power cycle, it acts as cold boot. I tried `echo disk > /sys/power/state` and it does not hibernate. Tried both kernel and tuxonice on sleep_mode with no success.

Since initially looking at this, I've discovered what was wrong: swap space was encrypted, thus hibernate doesn't know how to resume.

Solution [here](http://housegeekatheart.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/modify-encrypted-swap-partition-in.html) and [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq).

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with my Thinkpad T400 and Precise: After going to hibernation, the system would do a cold boot rather than resume from disk.

After playing with the solutions proposed here I found that all I had to do was add the kernel option

`resume=UUID=9e9418e7-25fc-49eb-8200-e8921a91a0cb`

to the list of options under `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT` in the file `/etc/default/grub`. 9e9418e7-25fc-49eb-8200-e8921a91a0cb is the UUID of my swap partition, (where the hibernation data is saved to). Needless to say, you have to change this according to your specific system!

Subsequently the bootloader configuration needed to be updated with

`sudo update-grub`

After that hibernation worked on the level of the kernel (i.e. using `pm_hibernate` or other CLI-tools). To enable triggering of hibernation from the user interface (KDE in my case) I had to install the policy-override as mentioned before and explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04).

Like Stephen, I use the kernel-side suspend function, as uswsusp does not work for me (freezes on resume). Up to now my Thinkpad has always resumed correctly with this configuration.

Comment: `resume=UUID=9e9418e7-25fc-49eb-8200-e8921a91a0cb` this UUID is specific to your machine only, it should be `resume=UUID=<UUID of swap partition>`. you can get the correct value by doing `sudo blkid /dev/sdxyy` where `sdxyy` is your swap partition

Answer (score 1):

This is how I fixed it for me -

To hibernate, run

```
$ sudo pm-hibernate
```

However, **if resuming fails after hibernation**, then

in `/etc/default/grub` file, replace the line

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

with

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="resume=/dev/sdaX"
```

Where, `/dev/sdX` is the swap partition.

After this, run

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

and hibernation should work now.

However, using this method, the screen doesn't lock after resuming, for which I've [asked a question here](https://askubuntu.com/q/148690/10146).