# Can you execute a custom shell command on power button or lid close?

Tags: 18.04, hibernate, lid

I am trying to make hibernate work on my Ubuntu 18.04.

I followed all the tutorials around (mostly from the answers here: [How can I hibernate on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-on-ubuntu-16-04))

So far, executing `pm-hibernate` on the shell works well and `systemctl hibernate` does not.

I am able to recover correctly from `pm-hibernate`, with the only problem that the screen is not locked, and I am logged in directly afterwards. I was able to fix that with adding an alias that manually locks, and executes pm-hibernate afterwards ([How do I lock the screen after resuming from hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148690/how-do-i-lock-the-screen-after-resuming-from-hibernation))

However `systemctl hibernate` does not work and if if come back after executing it on the command line, is the same as I have done a force power off.

In the power settings menu, I have selected 'hibernate', but it seems that this executes the same thing as `systemctl hibernate`, because after I press the power off button it is the same as if I have powered off.

I have tried adding a `resume` parameter in the grub configuration

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/nvme0n1p2"
```

where `/dev/nvme0n1p2` is my swap partition, but without any help.

So now my idea is to make the power off button execute my hibernate alias that locks and executes `pm-hibernate`? Also possibly on lid close?

At the moment I have to write hibernate in the terminal to go to hibernation.

Comment: I can't test this right now, but regarding the lid there is a good answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/526003/783023)

Comment: Yes, it's kinda possible with couple cheap tricks. I once wanted to write a script for that, but never got around to doing so.  Maybe I can write it in time for this bounty but probably there won't be enough time.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit this file `/etc/acpi/events/powerbtn`. action can be assigned to `<your hibernate script>`. Do let me know if this works out?

Comment: It does work, but it randomly when I come back from suspend it goes back again. Will try more. I was following the acpid manpage example: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/acpid.8.html