# I cannot use hibernate/sleep in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: laptop, hibernate, sleep

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable hibernation in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04)

I have 3.9 gb of RAM,261 gb of HDD, and 3.9 gb of swap (Toshiba laptop). The problem is that I cannot Hibernate OR Sleep the laptop for some reason. Any help?

Comment: what do you mean with "you can't" hibernate? doesn't it work or do you don't find the option to hibernate?

Comment: There exist multiple duplicates of this question. Please be more specific!

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous duplicates of this question but I'm gonna answer it anyways....

To get the 'Hibernate' option type the following command in the terminal >>

```
pm-hibernate
```

If your PC succeed in going to Hibernate mode and you have no problem waking it up, then you know your PC supports the Hibernate feature. Then again in the terminal type/copy-paste >>

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.desktop.pkla
```

then add the following:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Save (Ctrl + o) and exit (Ctrl + x).

Restart the PC. The Hibernate option should be visible under the 'Shut Down' dropdown.