# powernow-k8: Hardware error - pending bit very stuck

Tags: 12.04

new install of ubuntu 12.04 on a dual core AMD Turion X2

One of the problems while running is that the PC won't awaken from hibernation.

dmesg shows some errors that I don't understand:

powernow-k8: Hardware error - pending bit very stuck
   powernow-k8: transition frequency failed
   powernow-k8: failing targ, change pending bit set
   spurios 8259A interrupt: IRQ7.
   Fast TSC calibration failed
   Marking TSC unstable due to TSCs unsynchronized

Answer (score 0):

Welcome you here! Hibernation/Suspend has been disabled on Ubuntu 12.04 by default. You can enable it by [this way](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04) if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  Actually, the hibernation issue is more of just a sympton, as I've turned it off.  I'm really wondering why I'm getting "hardware error" and "TSCs unsynchronized" and "spurious interrupt IRQ7" errors.  Hopefully someone might have insight on that.