# How to make Lenovo Ideapad S10-3s netbook hibernate?

Tags: hibernate, lenovo, swap

My Lenovo Ideapad S10-3s, which is using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, does not hibernate. The error message shown is `PM: Not enough free swap`, although my swap is around 3GB and my RAM only around 1GB.

How can I make it hibernate? I have already tried doing this [How to enable hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04) to enable my hibernation.

#### Update

This is the screenshot after I used the `swapon -s` command suggest in neon_overload's answer:

[image: image of swapon -s result]

#### 2nd Update

I solved this problem by installing zramswap-enabler from:

http://modifyubuntu.com/12.04/#zram

or

http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/increased-performance-in-linux-with.html

After I installed zramswap-installer and rebooted my netbook, it is able to hibernate.

The screenshot of `swapon -s` after I installed zramswap-enabler:
[image: image of swapon -s result]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`swapon -s` will display how much swap you actually have mounted at the moment.

It is possible that you have a 3GB swap partition but for some reason it isn't being mounted.  It'll also tell you if there is anything abnormal about your swap *usage*.  If you continue to have problems, tell us the output of this command.

The swap partition is mounted in `/etc/fstab` (typically).

Another thing to keep in mind is that if you selected to encrypt your home directory during the Ubuntu install, your swap partition will also, by default, be encrypted.  Due to the way this is done it's no longer possible to hibernate (it would be difficult to have disk encryption but also allow hibernation and still be secure, and Ubuntu's chosen method of home directory encryption does not support it).

*Edit: as seen in the comments, it became apparent that this user had both zRam-based swap (which is like compcache) and disk-based swap, and solved his/her problem by installing zramswap-enabler.*

Comment: This is the screenshot after I used that commad:
[link](http://i1091.photobucket.com/albums/i393/mrn3xt/Screenshotedited.jpg)

Comment: Interesting, you have some compressed RAM-based swap there.  I'm afraid I don't know enough about it to know how it would affect hibernation - hibernation *should* be smart enough to ignore it, and just use the 3GB disk-based swap.  But it might be worth trying unmounting the zram-based swap and just using disk-based swap?  Maybe someone else can be of more help.

Comment: thanks for your idea about unmounting the zram, because when I searching how to unmount zram, I found these links, [link1](http://modifyubuntu.com/12.04/#zram) [link2](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/10/increased-performance-in-linux-with.html), which lead me intalling zramswap-enabler. After I insalled that package and reboot, my Lenovo netbook become able to hibernate.
NB: Sorry if my english doesn't very good.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve your problem.  Interestingly, your output of `swapon -s` after using zramswap-enabler appears to indicate that you've *removed* your zRam-based swap.  Not that that's necessarily a bad idea, since it was giving you problems (and is not part of a standard install).