# Hibernate command in 12.04 causes my PC to hibernate temporarily and restart

Tags: 12.04, hibernate, restart

Hibernate worked fine for my system in previous 10.10 and 11.04 versions.
I recently upgraded to 12.04. I did not see any hibernate command in the menu.

I made the change proposed in another Ask Ubuntu question. I tested hibernate using the `pm-hibernate` command but my system seemed to "hibernate temporarily" and then do an immediate restart! The same behavior is experienced after implementing the [How to enable hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04) guidelines. Do you know how can I fix that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [System does not hibernate; the screen flashes off for a few seconds and nothing else happens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151640/system-does-not-hibernate-the-screen-flashes-off-for-a-few-seconds-and-nothing)

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was happening because swap space was encrypted thus hibernate wont know how to resume

[This blog post](http://housegeekatheart.blogspot.com.br/2011/09/modify-encrypted-swap-partition-in.html) explains how to modify encrypted swap. [The swap page in the Ubuntu help wiki](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq) may help also.