# System does not hibernate; the screen flashes off for a few seconds and nothing else happens

Tags: 12.04, hibernate

I just upgraded my Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04. I have a problem with hibernation in my new 12.04.

I run the following command

```
sudo pm-hibernate
```

but my system does not hibernate, i.e. my system does not turn off; rather the screen just flashes out for few seconds and resumes previous state.

How do I fix this problem and enable hibernation on my system?

Comment: Have you checked your **BIOS** settings

Comment: @izx I thought so too...but come to think of it, shouldn't `sudo pm-hibernate` work even before hibernation is enabled in 12.04? That is the recommended way to test it first before enabling it...isn't it? What am I missing?

Comment: @EliahKagan - You're absolutely right - I jumped too fast. `sudo pm-hibernate` should work regardless of the polkit setting.

Answer (score 6):

Something in your hardware configuration is incompatible with the kernel's hibernation methodology. Unfortunately this is hard to troubleshoot unless the troubleshooter happens to have a very similar system.

You can try the alternative [TuxOnIce](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=tuxonice&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFoQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Ftuxonice.net%2F&ei=CHnNT9PtA6is2gXUpJCOAw&usg=AFQjCNFBdc42nzZG200xjt9PMuZOKQSI2w&cad=rja) ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TuxOnIce)) hibernation instead.

- *TuxOnIce* ([wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TuxOnIce)|[homepage](http://www.tuxonice.net)) is an alternative to the kernel's built-in hibernation technology, and is supposed to be compatible with a broader range of hardware, more reliable and more flexible.
- It is easily installed, and if it doesn't work for you, as easily removed.
- It does require installing *TuxOnIce's* custom kernel, but the instructions that follow should make it easy. If you've never opened the terminal before, you may want to now :-)

  #### 0. Requirements

  The only requirement for *TuxOnIce* is that your swap partition be *at least* as large as the amount of memory (RAM) you have. You can check this by:
- Start the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Type `free -m`, and you should see something like this:

  ```
               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
  Mem:          1024        731        260          0          0        190
  -/+ buffers/cache:        540        451
  Swap:         1536          6       1530
  ```
- The number after `Swap:` (e.g. 1536) should be *more* than the number after `Mem:` (e.g. 1024)
- If this is not the case, and your swap is *smaller* than your memory, you must either resize and increase the size of your swap partition, or configure *TuxOnIce* to use a special swap file. That is beyond the scope of this answer, but if you ask another question and mention it in the comments, I will answer and explain how.

  #### 1. Installing the TuxOnIce kernel
- Start the terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>
- Copy and paste the following into the terminal. This adds the *TuxOnIce* PPA and installs the custom kernel and headers.

  - ```
    sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tuxonice/ppa -y
    ```

    and once the ppa is added:
  - ```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install tuxonice-userui linux-generic-tuxonice -y 
    sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic-tuxonice -y
    ```
- Now reboot.
- Ubuntu should now start up with the *TuxOnIce* kernel. If there are any problems, keep the <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed at startup and you will get the Grub menu. Use the arrow keys to go to `Previous Linux Versions`, press enter, and press enter again to go back to the working kernel.

  #### 2. Testing hibernation functionality.
- Open some of the applications you normally use, e.g. Firefox, Thunderbird, LibreOffice, etc.
- Open the terminal again, with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>.
- Type `sudo pm-hibernate`, press enter, enter your password.
- You should see the lock screen for a second, and then the TuxOnIce hibernation progress screen, like the one below:

  [image]

  - If *TuxOnIce* works, your computer will shutdown.
  - Start it again, and wait. TuxOnIce should resume from the point you hibernated, including all the windows you opened at the position you opened.
- If all this worked, go to Step 3, which lets you enable Hibernate from the dashboard.

  #### 3. Enabling hibernation from the dashboard
- Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, type the below and then press enter:

  ```
  gksudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
  ```
- Paste the below, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to save and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to exit the editor:

  ```
  [Re-enable hibernate by default]
  Identity=unix-user:*
  Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
  ResultActive=yes
  ```

  [image]
- Restart, and you should see the *Hibernate* option as shown below:

  [image]

  #### 4. Removing TuxOnIce

  - If TuxOnIce doesn't work for you, or you simply wish to remove it, start the terminal and enter:

    ```
     sudo apt-get remove tuxonice-userui linux-generic-tuxonice linux-headers-generic-tuxonice -y
    ```
  - and remember to disable the Hibernate option in the menu with:

    ```
    sudo rm /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
    ```
  - Then restart.

Comment: You should mention this link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/178712/how-to-increase-swap-space-in-ubuntu in the answer if the user has not enough swap.

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me. In a console run:

```
sudo apt-get install uswsusp
```

Then you can try to suspend your computer with:

```
sudo s2ram
```

or hibernate with

```
sudo s2disk
```

If that works for you then just reboot and you should be able to hibernate later from the usual button (on the top right on Unity Desktop and selecting Hibernate).

I made a short tutorial of this and other issues for Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition available [here](http://www.librethinking.com/2013/09/tips-and-solutions-for-dell-xps-13.html).

Comment: Simple and works well. There is a typo however, the package name is `uswsusp`. Also, the hibernation didn't work on the first try: it powered off and then booted normally afterwards. I'm betting this is the traditional "restart to update config" thing.

Comment: wow, this is easy, hibernation worked on my Dell Latitude E6400 with Ubuntu 14.04 beta.

Comment: I didn't have no probs with hibernation back in 8.04. I'm pretty sure a lot of advanced users have it working flawlessly without "hacks".

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue before. If your swap partition is smaller than the amount of memory that you want to store in the hard disk when hibernating you may get this problem.

You can either re-size your swap partition, or use a swap file (it's a lot easier if you have no free space to re-size your swap partition).

Here is how to do it:

1. Open a terminal window (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or select **Applications > Accessories > Terminal**) or log in to remote server using the ssh client.
2. Create Storage File

   Type the following command to create 512MB swap file (1024 * 512MB = 524288 block size):

   ```
   sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile1 bs=1024 count=524288
   ```

   Sample outputs:

   ```
   524288+0 records in
   524288+0 records out
   536870912 bytes (537 MB) copied, 3.23347 s, 166 MB/s
   ```

   - `if=/dev/zero` means read from /dev/zero file. `/dev/zero` is a special file that provides null characters to build a storage file called `/swapfile1`.
   - `of=/swapfile1` means write storage file to `/swapfile1`.
   - `bs=1024` means read and write 1024 BYTES bytes at a time.
   - `count=524288` means Copy only 523288 BLOCKS input blocks.
3. Secure swap file

   Set up correct file permission for security reasons, by entering:

   ```
   sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile1
   ```

   A world-readable swap file is a huge local vulnerability. The above command makes sure only the root user can read and write to the file.
4. Set up a Linux swap area

   Type the following command to set up a Linux swap area in a file:

   ```
   sudo mkswap /swapfile1
   ```

   Sample outputs:

   ```
   Setting up swapspace version 1, size = 524284 KiB
   no label, UUID=0e5e7c60-bbba-4089-a76c-2bb29c0f0839
   ```
5. Enable the swap file

   Finally, to activate `/swapfile1` swap space immediately, enter:

   ```
   sudo swapon /swapfile1
   ```
6. Update `/etc/fstab` file
   To activate `/swapfile1` after Linux system reboot, add an entry to `/etc/fstab` file. Open this file using a text editor such as vi:

   ```
   sudo vi /etc/fstab
   ```

   Append the following line:

   ```
   /swapfile1 none swap sw 0 0
   ```

   Save and close the file. Next time Linux comes up after reboot, it enables the new swap file for you automatically.
7. How do I verify swap is activated or not?

   Simply use the `free` command:

   ```
   free -m
   ```

Here is the link from where i got this tutorial: [Add a swap file](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-add-a-swap-file-howto/)

Comment: A swap file does not need to be in `/etc/fstab` and this is not needed to enable it.

Answer (score -4):

As far as I know this does not work in 12.04. Somehow they did not include hibernate support as it was kind of buggy on some machines.

Comment: Hibernation is included in Ubuntu 12.04. [It's disabled by default, but you can enable it.](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04)