# How can I enable hibernation for a HP EliteDesk 800 G1 TWR machine?

Tags: 14.04, hp, hibernate

I've tried to hibernate my **HP EliteDesk 800 G1 TWR** PC using the command `sudo pm-hibernate` which exited with no message, error code 128.

The `man` page for `pm-hibernate` says:

> > > A return value of 128 means that pm-action tried to put the machine in the requested power state but failed.

Trying to run the same command again hung up my system completely.

According to `free -m`, I have 15960 MB RAM and with a 16295 MB swap space, which I think should be sufficient.

Then I found this [hardware certification page](http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/hardware/201407-15340/) that says "Hibernate is disabled on this system".

Is there any way I could enable hibernation?

Comment: You could look into your dmesg output, to see what's going on when you try to hibernate it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this post is an answer to your question, with two possibilities (TuxOnIce and uswusp):  [Problem with Hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151640/problem-with-hibernation)