# Hibernation option to system menu on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04

This answer worked fine with me on 12.04:

[Problem with Hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151640/problem-with-hibernation)

But now when I tried to use the same way to enable hibernate option to appear in the top bar system menu, it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found a working solution here:
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2014/04/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-14-04/

Question solved.