# Windows 7 not loading from Grub, Ubuntu 12.04 dual boot

Tags: boot, grub2, windows-7, grub-efi

I have the results of my boot script run here:

```
                      Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /boot/bcd

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''
mount: unknown filesystem type ''

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1   976,773,167   976,773,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048       411,647       409,600 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2         411,648       673,791       262,144 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sda3         673,792   391,383,039   390,709,248 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda4     391,383,040   657,863,679   266,480,640 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda5     924,344,320   976,773,119    52,428,800 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda6     657,863,680   916,189,851   258,326,172 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda7     916,189,852   924,344,319     8,154,468 Swap partition (Linux)

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 32.0 GB, 32017047552 bytes
256 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3877 cylinders, total 62533296 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1                   1 4,294,967,295 4,294,967,295  ee GPT

/dev/sdb1 ends after the last sector of /dev/sdb

GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdb1       8,392,704    62,531,583    54,138,880 -
/dev/sdb2           2,048     8,390,655     8,388,608 -

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        A444-E7DB                              vfat       SYSTEM
/dev/sda3        0EEC3E6EEC3E5067                       ntfs       OS
/dev/sda4        46DA0687DA067409                       ntfs       DATA
/dev/sda5        B6BA44F7BA44B621                       ntfs       Recovery
/dev/sda6        9ed25e19-3ede-4af3-9b4c-4c35c1c54e2e   ext4       
/dev/sda7        f0e890f9-acd1-4ee0-89b7-d2f1d0525247   swap       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda1        /boot/efi                vfat       (rw)
/dev/sda6        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)


=========================== sda6/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}

function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}

function load_video {
  insmod efi_gop
  insmod efi_uga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}

insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,gpt6)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9ed25e19-3ede-4af3-9b4c-4c35c1c54e2e
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_gpt
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,gpt6)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9ed25e19-3ede-4af3-9b4c-4c35c1c54e2e
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=en_CA
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="$1"
    if [ "$1" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ ${recordfail} != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "$linux_gfx_mode" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-26-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9ed25e19-3ede-4af3-9b4c-4c35c1c54e2e
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic root=UUID=9ed25e19-3ede-4af3-9b4c-4c35c1c54e2e ro   quiet splash pcie_aspm=force $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-26-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9ed25e19-3ede-4af3-9b4c-4c35c1c54e2e
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-26-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic root=UUID=9ed25e19-3ede-4af3-9b4c-4c35c1c54e2e ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic
}
submenu "Previous Linux versions" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9ed25e19-3ede-4af3-9b4c-4c35c1c54e2e
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic root=UUID=9ed25e19-3ede-4af3-9b4c-4c35c1c54e2e ro   quiet splash pcie_aspm=force $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.2.0-23-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
    recordfail
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9ed25e19-3ede-4af3-9b4c-4c35c1c54e2e
    echo    'Loading Linux 3.2.0-23-generic ...'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic root=UUID=9ed25e19-3ede-4af3-9b4c-4c35c1c54e2e ro recovery nomodeset 
    echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9ed25e19-3ede-4af3-9b4c-4c35c1c54e2e
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='(hd0,gpt6)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 9ed25e19-3ede-4af3-9b4c-4c35c1c54e2e
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry "Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,gpt3)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 0EEC3E6EEC3E5067
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry "Windows Recovery Environment (loader) (on /dev/sda5)" --class windows --class os {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ntfs
    set root='(hd0,gpt5)'
    search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root B6BA44F7BA44B621
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.

menuentry "Windows x86_64 UEFI-GPT" {
    search --fs-uuid --no-floppy --set=root 885C-ED1B
    chainloader (${root}/efi/Boot/bootx64.fi
}
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda6/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=9ed25e19-3ede-4af3-9b4c-4c35c1c54e2e /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=A444-E7DB  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults        0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=f0e890f9-acd1-4ee0-89b7-d2f1d0525247 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda6: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)

               =                boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
               =                boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-23-generic               2
               =                boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-26-generic               2
               =                boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-23-generic                  1
               =                boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-26-generic                  1
               =                initrd.img                                     2
               =                initrd.img.old                                 2
               =                vmlinuz                                        1
               =                vmlinuz.old                                    1

======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown GPT Partiton Type
5850cbb887c11947baf0379ca2d4c97e
Unknown GPT Partiton Type
dee2bfd3af3ddf11ba40e3a556d89593

========= Devices which don't seem to have a corresponding hard drive: =========

sdc 

=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
awk: cmd. line:36: Math support is not compiled in
```

I am having the problem where I can't boot windows from the grub menu. I get the `error: invalid efi path` on startup when I select my windows boot. I have an ASUS UX31VD. Any suggestions as to how I can get around this? I suck with boot configs.

Comment: Try referring [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/84501/how-can-i-change-convert-a-ubuntu-mbr-drive-to-a-gpt-and-make-ubuntu-boot-from) , & [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/151693/configure-dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-with-or-without-efi)

Comment: I didn't understand why you mentioned the absence of CD drive , if by that you mean , to boot the live Ubuntu Cd , or Windows 7 cd , please specify. Also you can boot to Ubuntu live through Usb. Drive

Comment: Type  `sudo update-grub` from Ubuntu in Terminal window. and observe if it mentions windows 7 or not , report here.I guess you need to install grub in EFI partition.

Comment: yes it mentions windows, sorry about the weird cd-drive post, I mean to say I cant run windows repair or anything from a cd

Comment: So can you boot to Windows now without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

- Run [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), update it, click `Recommended Repair`, write the final URL on a paper.
- Reboot the computer.
- In the GRUB menu, you should now see one (or several) new `Windows EFI` entry that allows to boot Windows. If not, indicate the URL.