# Ubuntu 12.04.1 and Windows 7 on same PC

Tags: boot, windows, uefi

Have Ubuntu installed on a 1TB SATA 3 Hard Drive.  Also have Windows 7 installed on a separate 1TB SATA 3 Hard Drive.  Unplugged Windows Hard Drive before installing Ubuntu as previous versions of Linux always destroyed my Windows installation.  What will happen when I plug in the Hard Drive with Windows 7?  Will I get a boot loader that will allow me to choose either OS or will 1 or both OS's get wiped?

The computer has UEFI support and uses the ASUS M5A-99X EVO motherboard.

Answer (score 3):

You installed Ubuntu without having the Windows HDD installed, which means that Ubuntu won't know about Windows until you update GRUB. If you want to boot both and have both on the same menu, then simply connected the Windows HDD, turn the PC on and make sure that the first Boot HDD Device is the HDD that has Ubuntu on it. Boot Ubuntu and on the desktop open a terminal and type the following:

`sudo update-grub`

GRUB will find the other hard drive and say "Hey there is a Windows partition here on this other hard drive... and it is bootable!". Then wait a couple of seconds an done.

Next time you boot a GRUB menu will appear asking you which system you want to boot to, Ubuntu or Windows.

Just in case, if the menu does not appear, either press <kbd>ESC</kbd> like crazy when the computer starts booting or hold <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> (Or a combination of both).

**UPDATE**: Since you have UEFI I urge you to read the answer provided in the following links:

[Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system/228069#228069)

[Configure Dual Boot, Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 with or without EFI](https://askubuntu.com/questions/151693/configure-dual-boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-with-or-without-efi?rq=1)

[Dual boot UEFI Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04 (both 64 bits). W7 entry doesn't appear in GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193144/dual-boot-uefi-windows-7-and-ubuntu-12-04-both-64-bits-w7-entry-doesnt-appea)

[How to boot Ubuntu from EFI/UEFI?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91484/how-to-boot-ubuntu-from-efi-uefi)

They will cover the cases related to having Windows on a PC that has UEFI support.

**UPDATE 2** - Did an actual test of what I said above. After connecting the Windows HDD again and running `update-grub` I got the following:

```
Generating grub.cfg ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-7-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-7-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-6-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-6-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-3.8.0-5-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-3.8.0-5-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
Found Windows 7 (loader) on /dev/sdc1
done
```

As you can see, GRUB found the boot loader of Windows 7 on that other HDD I just plugged in. I also removed the HDD again and ran `update-grub` which did exactly what I thought it would, remove Windows 7 from the list.

Comment: The order of the drives on the controller may also play a role depending on the BIOS/EFI. Just saying. +1

Comment: True. Am crossing my fingers he does not have an UEFI system. just the normal BIOS. In that case, it does not matter the order since they will get their assigned UUID and be added to the GRUB menu. He can even move the hard drives into another position and they will work just the same.

Comment: I DO have UEFI BIOS.  Motherboard is an ASUS M5A-99X EVO. Does this change the answer or is it still safe to do as you've outlined?

Comment: Yes, let me update the answer since it will not do you much unless you do a couple of other steps.

Comment: @apollo done, but it will take patience so try to have some before engaging the whole process. UEFI is not friendly if you add Windows to the mix.

Comment: Tried the solutions to no avail.  Getting that invalid Elf Magic error.  If I reinstall Ubuntu 12.04.1 on the other hard drive will it remove or alter my Windows 7 64 installation?  Also...have a back-up on a shared drive.  Will I be able to then restore Ubuntu?

Comment: @apollo Please feel free to email me at luisalvarado@ubuntu.com so we can solve this quickly since there are several scenarios where this could go with the use of UEFI and Windows on it.