# After boot-repair "Please install an operating system on your hard disk"

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, system-installation, windows-7

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 alongside windows 7. Because I could only boot Windows 7 I started Ubuntu live again from the DVD and ran boot repair.

Now the Computer is not able to boot anything. The error message "Please install an operating system on your hard disk" occurs.

[The boot repair output](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7155516/).

I'm not even able to get into the 'normal' BIOS anymore: first time it worked and I could have changed the boot-options, but I left without changing anything. Now, when I want to enter the BIOS, only System Diagnostics appears with four options to chose from.

Comment: So no answer worked. Could it be that I installed windows in legacy mode and ubuntu in efi?

I don't have a lot of stuff on this computer, so if I would just delete both OS partitions and install them again, that should work, shouldn't it? I need to have a windows os in one week for some days and could try installing ubuntu again afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest trying the instructions to repair grub on terminal, located [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/). (scroll down past the boot-repair instructions). It looks like all of your data/partitions are intact, grub is just not installed. The above link should help.

Let me know if it works!
DevNewb

Comment: Didn't work either, like the other answer using boot repair.

Answer (score 0):

A similar problem with yours was solved by following  [this workaround](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435160/cant-boot-windows-7-after-installing-ubuntu/435370#435370). It should work for your too. You need the original DVD from which you installed Win7, and you also need to download [BootRepair](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/?source=navbar) iso image and burn it on a regular CD or write it on some USB pendrive with Unetbootin tool. Detailed instructions are given in the provided link.

Remember to download the BootRepair iso image for your Ubuntu architecture, either 32bit image or the 64bit image.

Comment: I get the weird error message, after clicking on "Repair your computer", that "This version of Windows you are trying to repair is not compatible with the version of Windows you are trying to repair. ..."

Comment: That is odd. I suppose you are using the original DVD for your Win7 installation. Do not use a 32bit version to repair a 64bit installation and the other way around. Also, try to figure it out which version of Win7 are you using, it is Win7 SP1 or SP2? You need the right bootable DVD to be able to repair WIn7 boot and mbr.

Comment: Yeah it's really odd, as I installed Win7 from this disk 1.5 months ago. I now try to download the repair disk mentioned [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RestoreUbuntu/XP/Vista/7Bootloader), hope that works.

Comment: Those links are dead, the so called recovery disks for Win7. Maybe you should remove GRUB first with Boot Repair CD, and only after that try again to repair your Win7 boot and mbr with your original DVD.

Answer (score 0):

First of all get windows7 disk or flash installtion drive and repair ur boot by repair >command promt> type : fixMbr hope this will fix the problem and then follow this site http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/ and don forget to selct boot drive while instalingl ubunt.