# I could browse files in nautilus on other hdd partitions before, but can't anymore. Help!

Tags: 12.04, partitioning, nautilus

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 a few days back on my laptop alongside Windows 7. There was some problem during the installation and this corrupted the Windows 7 boot loader. Now I can't start Windows, but Ubuntu works pretty great.

Initially I could view the other Windows partitions in Nautilus (`C:`, `D:`, etc.) and I could view the files in them. (I never tried accessing any, :( ). But now only Home and File System are shown in nautilus. I ran this command:

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,SIZE
```

and it shows all the partitions correctly. So this means they exist. How do I get them to show up in nautilus? I really need to access some of the files until i get windows up and running( Which might take a while...). Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to [add entry](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab) for all of your partitions in `/etc/fstab`.On every boot, the partitions you added on `/etc/fstab` would be automatically mounted and gets detected by nautilus.

Comment: Some more detail about how to do it would help, probably a link to a tutorial. I am new to Ubuntu so I don't really know how to do this.

Comment: Thanks! I tried it using this [community help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Fstab). Works great!

Answer (score 0):

You can install PCMANFM, and use it as your fav file manager to browse all your partitions. Code:

```
sudo apt-get install pcmanfm
```

After finished with installing Pcmanfm you should go to Preferences -Advanced and check all 3 boxes related to mount partitions ... in Pcmanfm settings.

You can visit [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435160/cant-boot-windows-7-after-installing-ubuntu/435370#435370) to learn how to fix Win7 to dual-boot with Ubuntu.

Comment: Is there no way to get them to show up in nautilus, I mean they did before...

Comment: They will show if you choose to perform a fresh install of [Ubuntu 14.04](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/). You can wait until April 17th or not, as you wish. And there will also be other nice features that you will be able to use, like window menus and so on. Ubuntu 14.04 is a LTS release also like Ubuntu 12.04.4.

Comment: Actually they didn't show because they weren't mounted. Now they show just fine thanks to @AvinashRaj 's answer