# Troube DualBooting Ubuntu 14.04 after install on windows 7 disk

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-7, easybcd

I have spent countless hours over the past week following all kinds of tutorials to get Ubuntu 14.04 to run on my laptop alongside Windows 7, both x64. After systematically trying every seemingly sensible suggestion I now turn to you.

Brief summary of specs:

- Laptop Samsung ATIV Book 8 [870Z5E X04](http://www.samsung.com/de/consumer/notebooks-pcs/ativ-books/ativ-book/NP870Z5E-X04DE?subsubtype=ativ-book-8)
- Samsung 840 PRO SSD
- Windows 7 Pro x64 Installed over USB.
- backed up disk with Acronis Live USB before Ubuntu.
- Ubuntu 14.04 LTS Desktop x64 Live USB
- EasyBCD 2.2 installed on Windows

Now, for what I have been trying:

- Windows does NOT boot, if I switch BIOS to CSM or UEFI. Have to keep option BOTH activated.
- Ubuntu install does NOT give me the "install alongside" option. Always had to do either a clean install (worked fine but without windows anymore) or do "something else" in which case I created a "/" "swap" and "/home". Sometimes I even tried with a 1MB bios reserved boot. having the dropdown for bootloader choice below the table set to either sda or "/". imgur.com/FFjUVMr.jpg
- Boot-Repair ran over Ubuntu live USB several times. Never really got me anywhere.
- EasyBCD seemed like a sensible option and systematically added and tried out all the options available in the "Add New Entry" => "Linux/BSD" with every possible combination of the following: [ GRUB (Legacy), GRUB2, LILO/eLILO ] each with any option of [Autimatically locate and load, Partition 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6. As a result there is always the same error, telling me that:https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlY2S.jpg.

One thing that I noticed though: There is a 1MB of free, unallocated space visible in partitioning during install (not visible in Gparted) just before the Windows 100M sda1 partitioned FAT32. Except for that Windows only has it's own, main sda2.

Any ideas how to proceed?

Comment: So if you boot with UEFI+CSM then do "something else" it works ok? If so, what is the question?

Comment: No. My Computer does not successfully boot into Ubuntu AND Windows. Either I get rid of Windows and ubuntu boots or ubuntu does not boot

Comment: Did you mix installation modes? Both Windows and Ubuntu have to be either BIOS/CSM/legacy or UEFI, see [Can not boot Windows on Legacy BIOS after installing Ubuntu on UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/498531/can-not-boot-windows-on-legacy-bios-after-installing-ubuntu-on-uefi).

Comment: To workaround the "install alongside not appearing" problem, you can create the partitions for Linux in Windows disk manager, and then select "Something else" and manually set the partitions you created as / and swap.