# Dual boot windows 10 ubuntu 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows, uefi

Long story short , i inserted a windows 10 bootable USB deleted all partitions previously were installed , did this in command prompt :

```
diskpart
select disk 0
clean
```

then installed a windows 10 on the machine .
after that made a new bootable USB with ubuntu 16.04 , after booting the USB , 
before installing i had a warning saying somthing like :

> another operatin system (windows 10) is installed , using legacy BIOS
>   and you are trying to install ubuntu through uefi , if you continue
>   you might not be able to load the other operating system

i ignored it and went to install ubuntu, created a new partition alongside windows created a swap partition , and i the bootloader partition i think was the hard disk itself .
after finishing the installation i couldnt see windows entry in grub menu .
after searching i booted again into windows 10 usb and in command prompt i did :

```
bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr
```

this command deleted ubuntu grub and now im only able to load into windows 10 .
how can set up grub with both ubuntu and windows 10 entries ?

Comment: That warning Ubuntu gave you is the cause. You need to boot the Windows USB from your UEFI boot menu and install it before installing Ubuntu.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not boot Windows on Legacy BIOS after installing Ubuntu on UEFI](http://askubuntu.com/questions/498531/can-not-boot-windows-on-legacy-bios-after-installing-ubuntu-on-uefi)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what i did is , using [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) for creating a windows 10 and ubuntu 16.04 bootable images ,
**important** : when creating the usb under **partition scheme** select only 
UEFI with GPT disk (for both ubuntu 16.04 and windows 10) .

Turn on PC and :

- plug windows 10 usb into the machine
- click Esc (or your setup key) then Enter **setup menu**
- in BIOS settings disable secure boot (search for it under the tabs)
- enable CSM feature (under boot tab) this will let you boot from USB
- click f10 to exit and save changes .
- click Esc (or your setup key) then you USB should appear here
- click the usb and boot into windows 10 installation , on the screen install now click shift+alt+f10 this will open command prompt , do the following :

  diskpart
      select disk 0 - (in my case i wanted to install on disk 0) you can whatever you have 
          clean - this will clean any disk type (MBR or GPT)
- after you can partion and install windows 10 as you like .
- after installing windows 10 , remove windows 10 usb and insert ubuntu (created as above ).
- install ubuntu as you would do normally .