# Windows 7 won't boot after side-by-side installation of Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, grub2, graphics, windows-7

I installed Ubuntu 14.04.1 from a DVD I burned. Ubuntu runs perfectly, but when I select Windows 7 from GRUB, the screen goes blank (with some coloured lines at the very top of the screen). From here, the only way to get back to GRUB to force shut-down the machine from the power button.

I have updated grub2.

I have also tried boot repair, but all it did was create two Windows options from GRUB menu:

- Windows 7 (loader) (on `/dev/sda1`)
- Windows 7 (loader) (on `/dev/sda2`)

Both of them have the same result as earlier. Blank screen with some colourful pixels at the top of my monitor (top 2 or 3 pixels). Here's my boot repair [pastebin](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7862319/).

<sup>P.S. This is not a duplicate of [Can't boot Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435160/cant-boot-windows-7-after-installing-ubuntu) as I am able to select Windows from the grub menu but it crashes afterwards.</sup>

Comment: Maybe this post could help. http://askubuntu.com/q/224142/308840

Comment: why don't you use startup repair with a windows cd or any windows media?

Comment: @bain please remove the duplicate flag, I have specified as to why it is a separate problem and have discovered a solution and would like to post it as the answer.