# Can't boot windows 7 after installing Linux

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, windows-7

**SOLVED**

Had to change the windows system partition type which was flagged as "Swap" for some reason to NTFS system type.
I did this by logging into linux and changing it in the partition manager.
I rebooted, loaded my windows7 from the GRUB menu and finally was able to load the login screen.

**Old Question**

So I installed Linux Ubuntu on a separate partition to avoid conflicts with my windows install.
I had lots of problems solving the "install alongside" problem.
After I finally was able to do this, and rebooting my computer after a successful Linux install, I wasn't able to boot from windows 7.

I tried lots of solutions but none has been able to help me.

Some things that be relevant to mention:

Active operating system was windows 7, with pre-installed windows 8 on it (but not activated).
I don't have a CD-reader in my computer.

I have a grub-menu showing windows 7, but upon clicking on it, its stuck on the windows logo. It just stays there loading forever.

I ran bootinfo script; and this are its results:

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 112 for .

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Dell Utility: FAT16
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /DELLBIO.BIN /DELLRMK.BIN /COMMAND.COM

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 7
    Boot files:        /ubuntu/winboot/menu.lst /bootmgr /Boot/BCD 
                       /Windows/System32/winload.exe /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr 
                       /ubuntu/winboot/wubildr.mbr

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  Grub2 (v1.99)
    Boot sector info:  Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the boot sector of sda4 
                       and looks at sector 950258656 of the same hard drive 
                       for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
                       in partition 112 for .
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                  63        80,324        80,262  de Dell Utility
/dev/sda2              81,920    24,686,591    24,604,672  27 Hidden NTFS (Recovery Environment)
/dev/sda3    *     24,686,592   945,315,347   920,628,756  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda4         945,315,840   976,771,071    31,455,232  83 Linux


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        5450-4444                              vfat       DellUtility
/dev/sda2        D68A2A4B8A2A2887                       ntfs       RECOVERY
/dev/sda3        06EE2C2BEE2C1609                       ntfs       OS
/dev/sda4        43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a   ext4       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda4        /                        ext4       (rw,errors=remount-ro)


======================== sda3/ubuntu/winboot/menu.lst: =========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
debug off
hiddenmenu
default 0
timeout 0
fallback 1

title find /ubuntu/disks/boot/grub/menu.lst
    find --set-root --ignore-floppies /ubuntu/disks/boot/grub/menu.lst
    configfile /ubuntu/disks/boot/grub/menu.lst

title find /ubuntu/install/boot/grub/menu.lst
    fallback 2
    find --set-root --ignore-floppies /ubuntu/install/boot/grub/menu.lst
    configfile /ubuntu/install/boot/grub/menu.lst

title find /menu.lst
    fallback 3
    find --set-root --ignore-floppies /menu.lst
    configfile /menu.lst

title find /boot/grub/menu.lst
    fallback 4
    find --set-root --ignore-floppies /boot/grub/menu.lst
    configfile /boot/grub/menu.lst

title find /grub/menu.lst
    fallback 5
    find --set-root --ignore-floppies /grub/menu.lst
    configfile /grub/menu.lst

title commandline
    commandline

title reboot
    reboot

title halt
    halt
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=========================== sda4/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos4'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-57-generic root=UUID=43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-57-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-57-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-57-generic-advanced-43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.16.0-57-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-57-generic root=UUID=43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-57-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-57-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-57-generic-recovery-43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.16.0-57-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-57-generic root=UUID=43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-57-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-30-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-30-generic-advanced-43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.16.0-30-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic root=UUID=43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.16.0-30-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-3.16.0-30-generic-recovery-43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos4'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 3.16.0-30-generic ...'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-30-generic root=UUID=43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-30-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
    fi
    knetbsd /boot/memtest86+.elf
}
menuentry 'Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos4'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos4 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos4 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos4  43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a
    fi
    linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-D68A2A4B8A2A2887' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  D68A2A4B8A2A2887
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root D68A2A4B8A2A2887
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    chainloader +1
}
menuentry 'Windows 7 (loader) (on /dev/sda3)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-06EE2C2BEE2C1609' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos3'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  06EE2C2BEE2C1609
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 06EE2C2BEE2C1609
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    chainloader +1
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda4/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda4 during installation
UUID=43da45a0-e34e-41ce-ae71-5cf02c75de0a /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda4: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-cGaxV0L8/Tmp_Log: No such file or directory
```

Comment: STOP: Do not boot with Ubuntu and particularly with Ubuntu live installer as that uses swap. You have flagged your NTFS system partition as swap and any use of swap will overwrite it. And live installer always uses swap. Use a gparted live or parted magic live disk to boot as they do not by default use swap and change sda3 back from swap. Partition table shows sda3 as swap, but blkid still shows the NTFS, so it may be ok. But no guarantees.

Comment: Omg thank you soo much. I changed it in my linux system to NTFS and I can reboot now!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't boot Windows 7 after installing Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/435160/cant-boot-windows-7-after-installing-ubuntu)

Comment: My question is different.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend doing boot-repair

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair
```

You can get more information from here:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

"Active operating system was windows 7, with pre-installed windows 8 on it (but not activated)." What exactly does this mean? Why can't your first upgrade to Windows 8 or Windows 10- have a recovery disk(usb) and then do a fresh install? As this is a fresh new install you are not loosing much data.

Comment: I tried this before but didn't help :/

Comment: That doesn't work neither for some reason. I have the install disk but it wont' do anything when im on the screen to choose the partition to install it on.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change **grub.cfg** for Windows 7.

1. Boot your system to the GRUB menu.
2. Select (highlight) the GRUB boot menu entry `Windows 7 (loader) (on
   /dev/sda3)`
3. Press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the GRUB boot commands for Windows 7.

Your current boot command should look like:

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
set root='hd0,msdos3'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  06EE2C2BEE2C1609
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 06EE2C2BEE2C1609
fi
parttool ${root} hidden-
chainloader +1
```

Change it to

```
insmod part_msdos
insmod ntfs
insmod ntldr
set root='hd0,msdos3'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,msdos3 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos3 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos3  06EE2C2BEE2C1609
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 06EE2C2BEE2C1609
fi
parttool ${root} hidden-
ntldr ($root)/bootmgr
```

- Add the command `insmod ntldr`
- Change the command `chainloader +1` to `ntldr ($root)/bootmgr`

Press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot using these edited commands.

If this succeeds in loading the Windows 7, then you could make it permanent

1. Edit the file `/etc/grub.d/40_custom` and add the second, modified menuentry.
2. Run the command `update-grub` to update **grub.cfg** to include your customized entry.

Comment: I hate to say that this doesn't work for me.. when booting it gives me a weird purple-ish (grub colour-ed) screen white vertical white dots

Comment: You should try then fixing the Windows 7 with `Repair your computer` option from the Windows 7 Install Disc. Follow these steps: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/32523/how-to-manually-repair-windows-7-boot-loader-problems/ If this going to work you won't have Ubuntu listed on your boot menu but you can fix it, similar problem founded ova here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/139966/how-can-i-add-an-entry-for-ubuntu-to-the-windows-7-boot-menu

Comment: Fixed it by changing the partition type from swap to ntfs

Comment: Well done! How did you found that clue to do that?

Comment: "oldfred", the one who commented on my first question said there was a problem with the "swap" thing. I never would have found it! So I went to boot into Ubuntu Linux, went to my partition table and changed the Linux Swap/Solaris system type to HPFS/NTFS system type and it fixed it!