# Can't use dual boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows-7

So, I had Win7 installed on 128GB SSD and I planned to install Ubuntu 16.10 on my 1TB HDD. I made free space using EasyUS Partition Master and proceeded to install ubuntu from USB. Everything had gone(seemingly) smoothly but Win7 didn't appear on the grub list. I did partially repair it by following steps in the best answer([link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/435160/cant-boot-windows-7-after-installing-ubuntu)) but after that my PC booted straight into the Win7. What's more it started to work incredibly slowly and stopped recognizing my sound card. Everything went back to normal when I have removed Ubuntu's partitions and restored C drive to a point before the installation. Now the point is I really need Ubuntu and I'm a bit lost. Could you please help me?

I'm using Z77A-G43 MoBo with the latest version of BIOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution that worked for me:

Check if your windows boots in uefi or legacy mode(there are multiple tutorials online). Make sure that you boot your ubuntu dvd or USB in the exact same mode - f.e. you should have both "UEFI USB stick" and "USB stick"(legacy) in your BIOS boot options. Hope it will work for others as well.