# Can't boot into Windows 10 after installing

Tags: boot, dual-boot, windows, windows-10

I just installed Ubuntu on my PC. I used the "Install alongside Windows 10" option. Whenever I boot my PC up the only option I get is Ubuntu. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I wasn't able to get pictures but when I boot I go to a purple screen where the only option is Ubuntu and two other things (Something like Ubuntu recovery)

Here is the output of `fdisk -l`

```
$ sudo fdisk -l
Disk /dev/ram0: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram1: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram2: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram3: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram4: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram5: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram6: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram7: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram8: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram9: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram10: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram11: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram12: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram13: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram14: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/ram15: 64 MiB, 67108864 bytes, 131072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 931.5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x03af3d81

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          2048    1026047    1024000   500M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda2          1026048 1543919615 1542893568 735.7G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3       1543921662 1953523711  409602050 195.3G  5 Extended
/dev/sda5       1543921664 1920126975  376205312 179.4G 83 Linux
/dev/sda6       1920129024 1953523711   33394688  15.9G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.




Disk /dev/sdb: 28.7 GiB, 30752000000 bytes, 60062500 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x2c361bca

Device     Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *     2048 60062499 60060452 28.7G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)
```

Comment: Can you please expand on this question a little bit?  For example, are you able to login to Ubuntu ok? Can you access the Grub menu? Are you using UEFI? A screenshot or two would also be helpful :)

Comment: Please run `sudo update-grub` from the Ubuntu terminal, and reboot. See if Windows appears.

Comment: @ThatGuy Sure thing. I'm able to boot into Ubuntu just fine. How would I check if I'm using UEFI? Also here is the pastebin from me using `sudo fdisk -l` I'll try and add some other content into my question now.

Comment: @PatrickNegus I did this but Windows did not appear. It did complete successfully.

Comment: it seems you forgot to add the pastebin link

Comment: @Zalgo Whoops http://pastebin.com/PSt2UWCm

Comment: could you try the top few answers [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/435160/cant-boot-windows-7-after-installing-ubuntu?rq=1)

Comment: @Zalgo I tried the second one, it didn't work. I'll try the first one now

Comment: @Zalgo Please note that my internet is very bad so this will most likely be a one hour download.