# How to enable option of Hibernate in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: hibernate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable hibernation in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04)

I need Hibernate option in ubuntu 12.04.
It was in the older versions but not in 12.04. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open terminal and run this command:

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/hibernate.pkla
```

Copy, paste and save.

```
[Re-enable Hibernate]

Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Reboot your system.