# How do I get sleep and hibernate working on an Asus K53z?

Tags: 12.04, asus, sleep

Help!

New ASUS K53z laptop that has a fresh Ubuntu 12.04 install...

However, sleep doesn't work...

Tried to follow the manual process in this thread...

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1460790

The dropbox package was a 404, and my results are working...

closing the lid of the computer shuts the wireless off, and the screen remains lit up.

I'm a relative novice, but have been trying to work in terminal and follow instructions, but with this one I'm having little success.

Answer (score 1):

> Before enabling hibernation, please try to test whether it works
>   correctly by running `pm-hibernate` in a terminal. The system will try
>   to hibernate. If you are able to start the system again then you are
>   more or less safe to add an override.
>
> To do so, start editing
>
> ```
> sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
> ```
>
> Fill it with this
>
> ```
> [Re-enable hibernate by default]
> Identity=unix-user:*
> Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
> ResultActive=yes
> ```
>
> Save by pressing Ctrl-O and exit nano by pressing Ctrl-X
>
> Restart and hibernation is back!
>
> Some users will then need to run sudo update-grub to get the hibernate
>   option to be available in the power menu..

Take this how-to from [Hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/a/94963/73309)