# Will the "hibernate" feature ever be restored?

Tags: hibernate

From now on, will there never be a "Hibernate" feature in Ubuntu again (since it was known to contribute to data loss), or is the removal of the "hibernate" option only a temporary measure until the data loss issues are fixed? I find that it's easy to lose data now that the hibernate feature is gone and suspending the OS is the only option; will it be like this forever from 12.04 onward?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hibernate is still there in 12.04, it's just disabled by default. See [How to enable hibernation in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04) for how to enable it.

I don't know about the future plans but I guess it will stay this way unless it works reliable. In in the current version of 12.10 it's still disabled by default.