# Hibernate Option not available in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: power-management, hibernate

My Ubuntu 12.04 is missing Hibernate option so after searching a little on Google I came to know that this can solve my problem

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

Fill it with this

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Here is the link : [How to enable hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04)

After doing this I restarted my system. when the system booted it hanged ike anything No mouse movement no terminal no nothing. I waited for more than 1 hour Hibernate option appeared but i was not able to use my system anymore. any ideas ?

Comment: Why did you tag it with playonlinux?

Comment: I didnt found any other suitable tag.

Comment: Please tag your content suitably. [tag:hibernate] is a valid tag, as well as [tag:power-management], both of which existed well before this post was created.

Comment: Check this question too. http://askubuntu.com/q/196364/61218

Answer (score 1):

In this site are a very good how-to.

http://www.howtogeek.com/113923/how-to-re-enable-hibernate-in-ubuntu-12.04/

Sorry for my bad english, but i speak spanish.

Comment: Now I have a hibernate option in the power tab but it just turns off my system like Shutdown. and when I restart my system it is a fresh new session. No resume of my work.

Comment: @HussainNagri in [this post](http://askubuntu.com/a/156269/10616), there is an instruction to test whether hibernation works on your machine before enabling it.  That test is `sudo pm-hibernate`.  Did you run that test to see if hibernate works on your system or not?

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score -3):

One possible cause of being unable to hibernate is if you encrypted your home directory (and with it your swap partition).

Comment: "Just a thought" is not equal to an answer.

Comment: Comments are used to "ask authors about clarifications of the post." Please be obsessive with your own comments too. But, to clarify, every answer is the product of a thought.

Comment: Comments are also used to give extra ideas and half-answers. Please revise your answer to actually specify to decrypt the home directory, including all necessary command so that the OP may understand them.