# I have enabled hibernate but it isn't working. What can I do?

Tags: hibernate

I enabled Hibernate in 12.04 following the procedure given in this question : [How to enable hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/q/94754/61218)

But, Even after I enabled it, The hibernate isn't working. By not working, I mean the computer is hibernating correctly, but it is not resuming. I always given the login screen and a fresh session.

How can I enable hibernate that successfully resume?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Update for 16.04 (September, 2016)

Hibernate might not work not even it is successfully enabled if you have `btrfs` partitions. As revealed in a question here

- [How can I hibernate on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/768136/how-can-i-hibernate-ubuntu-16-04/820296#820296)

It was also revealed that enabling UEFI can cause problem with hibernation too.

---

### Enable the Hibernate option

To enable Hibernate, I followed [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/94963/61218) from Dima.

After enabling hibernate you will have an option to hibernate in the indicator session menu at top panel. But, though you can hibernate you may not resume from hibernate. You will just be given a new session. The fixes are below.

### The fixes to be able to resume from hibernate (12.04)

<sup>Several readers confirmed this working on 14.04 too</sup>

There is two way to fix this.

#### 1. Editing the `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` file

1. First get the UUID of the swap partition.

   ```
    sudo blkid | grep swap
   ```

   This will output a line similar to this:

   ```
   /dev/sda12: UUID="a14f3380-810e-49a7-b42e-72169e66c432" TYPE="swap"
   ```

   The actually line will not match with this. Copy the value of UUID in between `"..."` double quote.
2. Open the resume file

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume
   ```

   And in that file, add a line like this

   ```
   RESUME=UUID=a14f3380-810e-49a7-b42e-72169e66c432
   ```

   Don't forget to replace the actual UUID value you get from step 1. Save the file and exit gedit
3. Then in terminal, execute this command

   ```
   sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```

You will now be able to resume from hibernation

#### 2. Editing the `/etc/default/grub` file.

1. Open a terminal and execute the below command to open it

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. There will be a line like  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`
     . Edit the line to insert `RESUME=UUID=<your-uuid-value-here>` after the word `splash`.

   For example in my case, the line looks like this after editing

   ```
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=a14f3380-810e-49a7-b42e-72169e66c432"
   ```

   Make sure, you used your UUID value you get from `sudo blkid | grep swap` command.
3. Then do this command

   ```
    sudo update-grub
   ```

This also enable you to successfully get resumed from hibernate.

---

<sup>Tested on two Ubuntu installation, both worked</sup>

Comment: This worked for me in Ubuntu 14.04 as well.

Comment: It worked also on Xubuntu 14.04 with a LUKS partition and grub with double boot (W10 and Xubuntu 14.04).

Comment: Updated answer for 16.04 fixed this for me on Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 - great job keeping this updated