# Ubuntu doesn't save state after hibernation

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, power-management, hibernate, swap

As of yesterday, I had been using Ubuntu 14.04 with a 3GB swap-space. However, I was finding that I was unable to hibernate if I had more than 3GB of RAM in-use. So, I booted on a LiveUSB of Gparted, I deleted my swap partition, shrunk my */dev/sdb1/* file system (the main one--where the operating system is), and then created a larger swap-space partition; it's now a

However, now when I hibernate, the state isn't saved. I've already edited my */etc/fstab* file to account for the new UUID of the partition--but it won't work. I've made sure the swap is enabled, ran the command `swapon -s`
and it looked good--I think.

Here are various screenshots of the information I've given.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBqu1.jpg

I had hibernation working perfectly prior to my resizing the swap-partition.

EDIT: my pm-suspend.log yields this: http://pastebin.com/ptzSnyB2 
Something fishy with the *thaw* commands. (??)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it. Turns out my `resume` file wasn't updated to account for the new UUID! I followed everything in the link below and hibernation works again.

https://askubuntu.com/a/196365/123256