# I can't get suspend, hibernate and shutdown to work in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, shutdown, suspend, hibernate

I recently built a computer with these specs: Asus Motherboard, Intel i3 3.3 GHz dual processor, 8 GB of RAM. I installed 12.04 on a brand new hard drive.  I partitioned the hard drive between root, home and swap like I have often read how to do.

I cannot get this machine to properly shutdown.  I have to hold the power button down now.  Although, for the first few days it properly shutdown.

I also cannot get the system to *hibernate or suspend* properly.  I have read tons on this and watched many YouTube tutorials on how to fix both, but the computer never wakes up after suspend or hibernate. It just stays on a black screen.

Can anyone help?  I love 12.04 so far, but these setbacks are making me worried about stability and power management issues.  Also, I wonder if it's really bad for the hard drive to force the CPU to shutdown.

Comment: for hibernate http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04

Answer (score 1):

By swap he means the swap partition. [Swap or paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging)
To check your swap partition, you could do one of these:
Go to Ubuntu Software Center, and install gparted.
There you can check all your disk partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know is you have solved your problem but if not, **check if you have enough swap**.

The swap partition must provide to receive the contents of the memory. Usually a 1 GB Swap enough. But if you want to hibernate the machine, the easiest way is to make sure the swap size is larger or equal to the amount of RAM you have.

Comment: Can you expand this answer to explain how to do this?

Comment: This would only really address the hibernation issue. If there are also issues with shutdown and suspend, then the problem might lie elsewhere.

Comment: Swap partition need not be equal to or larger than RAM. Please explain, if it is, or mention the source that claims this to be a criteria.

Answer (score -1):

To use hibernation, your swap partition should be **at minimum** the same size as your RAM.

In your case it has to be **at least**  **8 GB**

Comment: No, there is no criteria as such, please mention the source where you got this.

Comment: i have no idea why I've been down-voted. my answer is similar to slc66's answer(which i edited). I have a windows background  so i know the hibernation file is the size of your ram. My ubuntu install did not hibernate until i resized the swap using Gparted @jobin

Comment: As I said earlier, that is no criteria for hibernation to be enabled. And if you still believe it is, please provide a reference as to how you claim this. **P.S.** I have a 4 GB RAM and approx. 2 GB swap partition and I have hibernation enabled in both my operating systems: Windows 7 as well as Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: @jobin. windows uses a hiberfil.sys file for hibernation but unices use a swap partition