# Why can't I hibernate my Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, power-management, hibernate, command-line

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to enable hibernation in 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation-in-12-04)

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and don't have the hibernate button anywhere. Isn't there any way by which I can set up the hibernate button rather than running the command: "sudo s2disk" everytime from the terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Terminal.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/hibernate.pkla
```

Copy and paste the following code in file:

```
[Re-enable Hibernate]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

[image]

It will appear in the power menu!