# No suspend/hibernate after last apt-get upgrade

Tags: 12.04, suspend, hibernate

suspend does not work anymore after my last apt-get upgrade on my precise Lenovo X200. I couldn't find any error messages besides:

```
# sudo pm-suspend
flock: 3: Bad file descriptor
```

There is no syslog/messages output when executing that command.

Any ideas?

Cheers,

Jan

Comment: i found a topic about [hibernate enabling](http://www.askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation). but i didnt find anything for suspend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't a direct fix to the problem, but uswsusp may be able to provide you with alternative suspend and hibernation programs.

To install the package, run `sudo apt-get install uswsusp`. Run the `s2ram` program to suspend your computer and `s2disk` to hibernate. `s2both` can be used for hybrid suspension (similar to `pm-suspend-hybrid`).

More information regarding installation of uswsusp on Ubuntu is available [here](http://blog.paulbetts.org/index.php/2007/02/11/fixing-software-suspend-hibernate-with-uswsusp-in-ubuntu-feisty-and-edgy/).

Comment: It is pretty old (2007) does it work for you? For which ubuntu version?

Comment: works. read this: http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/uswsusp