# Neither suspend nor hibernate in 12.10 lubuntu - is there a workaround by scripts?

Tags: 12.10, lubuntu

I've neither suspend to ram nor to disk in 12.10 lubuntu (i suspect there might be a kernel issue but i'm only a simple user). Also, the xfce powermanagement which comes with lubuntu by default does not have any effect. Even it doesn't lock the screen when i set this in the preferences: What do when close the lid.

So, on a portable that's annoying a lot. Is there some way to workaround by scripts in `etc/pm/*.d`?

Searching around i found something interesting in my syslog:

```
laptop-mode: Warning: Configuration file /etc/laptop-mode/conf.d/board-specific/*.conf is not readable, skipping.
```

And then:

```
laptop-mode: enabled, not active
```

The "incriminated" directory `/board.specific/`, in my computer does simply not exist! Now, i don't seem to be the only one affected by this problem. There is something like a bug filing against this in Debian. May be, someone knows how to overcome this problem?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install powernap` followed by `pm-suspend` or `pm-hibernate`

Comment: Thanks for sharing the idea. Unfortunately it did not have any effect.

Comment: Does anything happen when you try to suspend? Post your /var/log/syslog on paste.ubuntu.com and add the link to the question so we can help you out.

Comment: Done. It's pasted as 'paste.ubuntu.com/1315305'

Comment: You need to add this information into your question, not buried in the comments, that way your question is bumped!

Answer (score 1):

This is a duplicate question, I'll just send you in the right direction... I hope.

In Ubuntu 12.04 and newer, [hibernation has been disabled by default in policykit](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/policykit-desktop-privileges/+bug/812394).

Follow the indications posted [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation)