# How ubuntu hibernate happen?

Tags: hibernate

hello guys I'm pretty new to this site. I want to learn how the hibernate happening in ubuntu, Can anyone suggest me a place? I have done googling but still no luck. thanks..!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enable hibernation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know to what extent you needed to learn but as the first step you could take a look at Ubuntu Documentation. [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PowerManagement/Hibernate)'s the link.

Comment: Well thank you @Sudheera , But I want something more than this. anyway, thanks..

Comment: If you noticed there are some links on additional information at the bottom of the given web page take a look..!

Comment: Ah, that's gonna be very helpful, Thanks sudheera..!