# Screen does not wake up after hibernation

Tags: screen, hibernate

After running `sudo pm-hibernate` my computer starts working but screen remains black. My memory is 7.9 GiB and my swap partition is 8 GiB. What can I do to resolve it?

Comment: Possibly this guide to install **Tux on Ice** could be solution for you: http://askubuntu.com/a/356289/58470