# Remember windows after reboot

Tags: unity, session

Is there a way to remember the windows I had opened in a session after reboot on unity?

I'm aware that is possible on KDE and gnome, but is it possible on unity?

Comment: Are you looking for something like the `hibernate` option?

Comment: @Jobin, perhaps... What is the main difference between them?

Comment: When you hibernate your computer, all open windows are saved to disk and all of them are reopened in the same state when you resume. The computer is powered-down, unlike suspend which consumes power. You need to enable hibernation in Ubuntu: look here for the method: http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation

Comment: @Jobin, so what is the difference with gnome's save session?

Comment: @Barefeg: I am sorry I am not aware of what gnome-session-save does.