# Hibernate not working 13.04: screen flashes / blanks out and locks

Tags: 13.04, hibernate

I am using Ubuntu 13.04. I face problem in hibernate option. I have created swap disk also enabled hibernate option referring the manual. Whenever I select hibernate the screen flashes / blanks out and locks. Obviously its not going to hibernate mood.

Am I missing something? Please help.

Comment: on blank screen ... do you see the cursor blinking on left upper corner ?

Comment: yes.. sometimes.. also rarely i get messages like "1 process is not able to freeze"...kinda

Comment: i m posting my answer check in few mints

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I installed Kubuntu 13.04 on my laptop, hibernate would behave as you mentioned... I fixed it by disabling my Bluetooth module. It would appear that on occasion Bluetooth, WLAN, and Ethernet drivers can interfere with hibernation.

Perhaps try disabling them systematically and see if your hibernation issue still occurs.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you tell me in detail how to disable them before hibernating? do i need to do it everytime or the setup is onetime? pls advise.

Comment: Can you let me know on how to disable them manually.

Answer (score 0):

Try this link [How to enable hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation)

In short do this:

1. Type in the following at prompt (this example uses `gedit` as editor):

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
   ```

   If the file already exists, it might be a good idea to save a backup copy.
2. Fill it with this:

   ```
   [Re-enable hibernate by default]
   Identity=unix-user:*
   Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
   ResultActive=yes
   ```
3. Save the file and reboot.

It worked for me on HP-540 laptop without disabling anything

Comment: I tried it still, I face the same problem.