# Hibernation still not available

Tags: hibernate

tried the workaround posted here [How to enable hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation) but not even after rebooting, updating grub or kilall unity-panel-service commands do reset unity but no hibernation is available on "start" button.  when sudoedit file saves as /vm etc etc, tried chaging this name to the /etc/polkit loclauth etc etc but wouldnt let me save the file there must be doing something wrong, because I browse to /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d and there are no files there

Comment: Which Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: This probably was about saucy during development and should have been a bugreport instead. I opened a new question for the final version 13.10 and opened a bugreport http://askubuntu.com/questions/361734/hibernation-is-still-missing-from-menu-in-13-10-after-enabling-via-polkit-how-t