# Hibernate Ubuntu 13.04 Lenovo X1

Tags: lenovo, hibernate

I understand that the Lenovo ThinkPad X1 ultrabook supports hibernation, however I cannot work out how to get it working. I have already created a swap partition. I tried to run `sudo pm-hibernate`, but it has no effect.

Edit.....................

```
upower -d | grep can-hibernate
```

output

```
can-hibernate:   no
```

for

```
free-m
```

output

```
               total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
  Mem:          7687       3399       4287          0         88       1936
  -/+ buffers/cache:       1375       6312
  Swap:         7887          0       7887
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please include the output of `upower -d | grep can-hibernate` and `free -m` in your question?

Comment: `can-hibernate:   no`                                                

-----------------------------------------------------------------                                        

`total         used       free     shared    buffers     cached

Mem:          7687       6246       1440          0        145       2904

-/+ buffers/cache:       3196       4491

Swap:         7887       1183       6704`

Comment: Please **edit** your question to include more details - it is how this site works. And comments aren't fit for formatted output - I really cannot read it like that.

Comment: Sorry yeh, Edited the main question with the output of `free -m` and `can-hiberate`

Comment: I may be wrong, but is hibernation enabled? http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation

Comment: @LiveWireBT That Q&A is about how to enable it in PolicyKit, so that a regular user can hibernate the machine. However, `sudo pm-hibernate` really should work without these steps. This is also outlined in the accepted answer there.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to Suspend to RAM or Disk? (suspend to RAM is faster and requires power ONLY to ram)?

More details:

```
pm-suspend
           During suspend most devices are shutdown, and system state is saved
           in RAM. The system still requires power in this state. Most modern
           systems require 3 to 5 seconds to enter and leave suspend, and most
           laptops can stay in suspend mode for 1 to 3 days before exhausting
           their battery.
pm-hibernate
           During hibernate the system is fully powered off, and system state
           is saved to disk. The system does not require power, and can stay
           in hibernate mode indefinitely. Most modern systems require 15 to
           45 seconds to enter and leave hibernate, and entering and leaving
           hibernate takes longer when you have more memory.
```

> **NOTE**: there is also a hybrid mode which is in between suspend to RAM and Disk.

Find what states are supported by your laptop, for example (supports both to ram and disk):

```
cat /sys/power/state
mem disk
```

You can do it from command line anyway:

**Option 1**: use `pm-utils` (need to install the package and user needs to have privilege to do suspend)

Suspend to RAM: `sudo pm-suspend`

Hibernate (to Disk): `sudo pm-hibernate`

**Option 2**: directly change `sysfs` (requires root privilege)

Suspend to RAM: `echo "mem" > /sys/power/state`

Hibernate (to Disk): `echo "disk" > /sys/power/state`

Refere to [System Power Management State](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/states.txt)

Comment: Apparently you did not read the question. OP clearly states running `sudo pm-hibernate` has no effect and that the capabilities for hibernation aren't being detected. And if you want to request further clarification on suspend/hibernate, please do that in a comment, not in an answer.