# low on battery mode

Tags: power-management, battery

On my lenovo laptop with Windows installed, when my battery was almost empty, it went in sleep (or some sort of sleep mode). so that if i gave it power again, it restarted back to windows with all my stuff still open.
But on ubuntu it's just uses it till it's empty.

Does Ubuntu has some similar sort of option ?

btw: a small second question; when i press the ' button,  i need to press the spacebar to let it be displayed. Is it possible to just let it be showed when i pressed it?

thnx in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got to Power settings:
[image: Search for Power settings in Dash]

Then you should be able to set how it behave:
 [image: Set 'When Power is critically low' to 'Hibernate']

Make sure you [enable hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation) first.

Comment: thanks, but the option "hibernate" is grayed out at my side. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10