# Hibernate option missing in ubuntu 12.04, after extending the Root partition

Tags: 12.04, unity, gparted, hibernate

Till yesterday, the hibernate option was enabled and working perfectly fine.

Today morning, I have extended the root partition by adding some extra free space to it.
I used the **gParted** tool in the **Ubuntu live session** for doing this.

After extending the root partition, I see the hibernate option not getting displayed in the system's shutdown-menu.

PS:
I have tried the guide at this [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation). But, it didn't work.

[image]

Comment: Could you upload a screenshot of how the disk looks in `gparted`? In particular, make sure that your swap partition is still larger than your total RAM.

Comment: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5691535/GParted.png

Answer (score 0):

Try editing this file: **sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla** like this:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install the hibernate feature again.Open Terminal and enter following command:

> `sudo gedit /var/lib/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/hibernate.pkla`

copy and paste the following code in file:

[Re-enable Hibernate]

```
Identity=unix-user:* Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes
```

Save file and Exit, then Restart and check.