# 15.10 Hibernate not powering PC off

Tags: power-management, shutdown, hibernate

Ubuntu 15.10 with 4.4 kernel on Dell XPS 15 9530 (new one).

System do not powering itself off after hibernation. Executing pm-hibernate does almost all except notebook will stay under power.
The display and disks are off, keyboard is on, USB power is on.

If I manually switch system off/on (holding power button) - it will boot in to hibernated environment (all apps etc. will be there for me).

For reference if I issue shutdown `shutdown -P now`the system will terminate and power off all hardware correctly.

So my question is what is wrong with pm-hibernate?

I tryed powermanagment-tools and a command 
`dbus-send --system --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.login1 /org/freedesktop/login1 "org.freedesktop.login1.Manager.Hibernate" boolean:true`

with no success.

Please ask for additional info - will post it asap.

Comment: Try [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/94963/400278) post out.

Comment: Alex, I did read this post. My case is not that it is not hibernating. It simply is not powering things off. But I will read it again =)