# How to hibernate in Ubuntu gnome 14.04

Tags: gnome, hibernate

I don't see any hibernate option in my distro. And moreover I installed `gnome-tweak-tool` and tried to change "`When power button pressed`" setting to hibernate but that doesn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable hibernation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you use Gnome-Shell press the power drop down:[image]

Then on your keyboard press the 'alt'-key, and the menu should look like this:
[image]

The pause button puts the computer in hibernation