# Enable Hibernate

Tags: 14.04, hibernate, windows-10

I have a Windows 10 in Local Disk (C:) and a Linux Ubuntu 14.04 in Local Disk (D:). When I wanted to install Ubuntu for the first time, I turned off the Hibernation in Windows. Could I enable it again in Windows? and Could I enable Hibernation in Ubuntu? If I enable "Hibernate" in Windows/Ubuntu, Do I face some problems (like loss of data) or not? Thanks.

Comment: Search how to enable Hibernation in Windows. There are guides everywhere.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable hibernation?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation)

Comment: You can enable hibernation in Windows, but you will not be able to mount Windows partitions, if Windows has been hibernated.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the official documentation [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/power-hibernate.html) and first you need to test if hibernate works or not.

- Press **Ctrl+Alt+T** to open a terminal
- Type `sudo pm-hibernate` and press **enter**.

  - You might be asked for your login password. Type it.
  - Your computer should turn off.
- Switch it back on.

If you application (such as the terminal you used above) are still there, that means hibernation works!

If your machine rebooted from scratch after you turned it on, or if it didn't turn off at all (i.e. if it only blinked and came back online immediately), then it means hibernation doesn't work yet on your computer.

If hibernation works, you can enable it by editing a [PolKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polkit) file, by typing this command on the same terminal you opened above:

```
sudo nano /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-hibernate.pkla
```

and add the following text into that file:

```
[Re-enable hibernate by default in upower]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.hibernate
ResultActive=yes

[Re-enable hibernate by default in logind]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate;org.freedesktop.login1.hibernate-multiple-sessions
ResultActive=yes
```

Save by pressing **Ctrl**+**O** then enter and then exit nano by pressing **Ctrl**+**X**. Now the hibernation should ready to be use by you, this should work.