# How to undo the changes made through nano?

Tags: hibernate, nano

I'm a newbie to ubuntu. i'm using ubuntu 16.04 on my desktop.

Recently I found a way to add 'hibernation' option to menu on

I tried it and was successful. But how to undo the changes I have made with nano and remove the 'hibernate' option from menu?

Comment: Please add what you did (each command) and we can help you. Like this it is mainly guesswork (use `history` in command line to track commands you used and copy/paste them into the question ;) )

Comment: Which instruction you followed?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you enabled hibernation on your Ubuntu. For example, If you followed this instruction https://askubuntu.com/a/487282/61218, All you need to do is to delete the file `/etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/52-enable-hibernation.conf`.

The command to delete that file will be

```
sudo rm /etc/polkit-1/localauthority.conf.d/52-enable-hibernation.conf
```