# Ubuntu 16.04: No Display ouput after wake up

Tags: 16.04, suspend, monitor

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on my PC. This morning I put it into Suspend and when I woke it up again there was no display output anymore. It just "tried" to go on and then showed 'no signal' in regular intervals.

The lights of the mouse and keyboard went on but I could not really test if they were working, and the lights next to the power button were blinking too.

I tried connecting the monitor to the motherboard and had no reaction at all. I tried booting with my live usb and had the same result as without it. Finally I tried connecting the monitor to my laptop with windows 10 and it works fine.

Is there any way to fix this by myself?

Comment: Try hibernate http://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation#94963