# Laptop heating up when put it in bag

Tags: power-management, overheating

When I close my laptop lid (sleep: blinking power light) and put it in bag, it heats up too much. I found out that this is because CPU, GPU and Harddisk are still running when the laptop is in sleep mode and the air ventilation is not good.

How can I put CPU and GPU into idle states when my laptop is in sleep mode?

When I'm running Windows, it is ok to put the laptop in a bag while it's in sleep mode because the CPU and GPU are in idle state; even system fans are not running.

Is it possible to stop CPU and GPU running in sleep mode on Ubuntu?

- Ubuntu version : 16.04.
- CPU : i3 6100U
- GPU : Nvidia GT 940MX

Answer (score 2):

I think Suspending your system keeps parts on, like you said.  That is the default for Ubuntu. Windows, on the other hand, uses Hibernate by default.  Try using Hibernate instead

[How to enable hibernation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94754/how-to-enable-hibernation)

Comment: No, Windows also use sleep, too. In Windows, if RAM is removed during sleep, all sessions lost.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better if you find out whether SLEEP (which is called as SUSPEND  in Ubuntu) really works for you. If sleep isn't working properly, then it's as good as only turning off the screen and keeping all other things running.

So see if comparable heating occurs when you put your laptop to SUSPEND and leave it on the desk.

If SUSPEND not working is the reason, then you might have to work on getting that working, which could automatically fix your present issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late. But I was having this issue and couldn't find an answer online. For me the fix was to disable "Power on lid open" in the BIOS.