# How to switch to plane mode before suspend

Tags: wireless, suspend

I have a Slimbook and I noticed that once suspended (close the lid), it would wake up if there is any transmission with the bluetooth mouse.

And in fact, when suspended, there is no reason why the computer would keep the wireless active.

The workaround is to manually switch of the wireless (plane mode) before suspending, but I guess it would be possible to automate that.

How can I do?

Answer (score 1):

After enabling programmatic suspend in your system with this script*:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d/com.ubuntu.enable-suspend.pkla  
[Re-enable suspend by default]  
Identity=unix-user:*  
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.suspend  
ResultActive=yes  
EOF
```

Create a script with the following then make it executable.

```
#!/bin/sh
rfkill block bluetooth
rfkill block wlan
exit 0
EOF
```

Create a symlink to it from your lappy's desktop; click and close your [very nice rig](https://slimbook.es/en/kde-slimbook-2-ultrabook-laptop)!

- Thanks to [kiri](https://askubuntu.com/users/176889/kiri), a dinkum cobber, for the [script](https://askubuntu.com/a/364818/197910).